# INSERT default values on the list of results of a query

Tags: sql, birt

I have to change a query, and want to add some pre-defined results (outputs) to the query when two values are found on two different columns.

Basically I want to add values to a new column on a query. I tried to use `CASE` but no luck until now.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
Q1.SCHD_ID,
Q1.SCHD_DESC,
Q1.TIMEZONE_ID,
Q1.DISPLAY_IN_SCHD_TZ,
Q1.LOGO_ID,
Q1.CODICE_SKOFF,
Q1.CODICE_MODULO,
case
when (Q1.PIANO_CODICE = 'FND001' AND Q1.CODICE_SKOFF = '2346') THEN 'testA'
WHEN (Q1.PIANO_CODICE = 'FND001' AND Q1.CODICE_SKOFF = '2347') THEN 'testB'
WHEN (Q1.PIANO_CODICE = 'FND001' AND Q1.CODICE_SKOFF = '3287') THEN 'testC'
WHEN (Q1.PIANO_CODICE = 'FND001' AND Q1.CODICE_SKOFF = '0000') THEN 'testD'
WHEN (Q1.PIANO_CODICE = 'TEST' AND Q1.CODICE_SKOFF = '4435') THEN 'testE'
ELSE 'NULL'
END as TITOLO_MODULO_SO

FROM

(SELECT
  sc.SCHD_ID, 
  sc.SCHD_DESC,
  sc.TIMEZONE_ID,
  sc.DISPLAY_IN_SCHD_TZ,
  SUBSTR(su1.USER_VALUE, 1 ,3) as LOGO_ID,
  su1r.USER_DESC as PIANO_FINANZIAMENTO,
  su1r.USER_ID as PIANO_CODICE,
  cu1.USER_VALUE as TITOLO_MODULO,
  cu2.USER_VALUE as CODICE_MODULO,
  c.CPNT_TITLE as ARGOMENTO,
  sr.START_DTE,
  sr.END_DTE,
  cu3.USER_VALUE as DURATA_CORSO,
  su4.USER_VALUE as CODICE_SKOFF
   FROM PA_SCHED sc
-- Campo "Piano principale di finanziamento"
left outer join PA_SCHED_USER su1 on sc.SCHD_ID = su1.SCHD_ID and su1.COL_NUM = 50
left outer join PA_USRRF_SCHED su1r on su1r.COL_NUM = su1.COL_NUM and su1.USER_VALUE = su1r.USER_ID
-- Informazioni ITEM
left outer join PA_CPNT c on c.CPNT_TYP_ID = sc.CPNT_TYP_ID and c.CPNT_ID = sc.ACT_CPNT_ID and c.REV_DTE = sc.REV_DTE
-- ITEM -> Titolo per finanziamenti
left outer join PA_CPNT_USER cu1 on cu1.CPNT_TYP_ID = c.CPNT_TYP_ID and cu1.CPNT_ID = c.CPNT_ID and cu1.REV_DTE = c.REV_DTE and cu1.COL_NUM = 10
-- ITEM -> Codice Finanziamento
left outer join PA_CPNT_USER cu2 on cu2.CPNT_TYP_ID = c.CPNT_TYP_ID and cu2.CPNT_ID = c.CPNT_ID and cu2.REV_DTE = c.REV_DTE and cu2.COL_NUM = 100
-- ITEM -> Ore finanziamento
left outer join PA_CPNT_USER cu3 on cu3.CPNT_TYP_ID = c.CPNT_TYP_ID and cu3.CPNT_ID = c.CPNT_ID and cu3.REV_DTE = c.REV_DTE and cu3.COL_NUM = 90
-- Dati della Scheduled Offering
left outer join PS_SCHD_RESOURCES sr on sr.SCHD_ID = sc.SCHD_ID
-- Facility
left outer join PA_FACILITY f on f.FACILITY_ID = sc.FACILITY_ID
-- Location
left outer join PA_LOCN l on l.LOCN_ID = sr.LOCN_ID
-- Campo "Banca capofila"
left outer join PA_SCHED_USER su3 on sc.SCHD_ID = su3.SCHD_ID and su3.COL_NUM = 10
left outer join PA_USRRF_SCHED su3ref on su3ref.COL_NUM = su3.COL_NUM and su3ref.USER_ID = su3.USER_VALUE
-- Campo "Multisocietario"
left outer join PA_SCHED_USER su2 on sc.SCHD_ID = su2.SCHD_ID and su2.COL_NUM = 30
-- Campo "Codice Finanz. SKOFF"
left outer join PA_SCHED_USER su4 on sc.SCHD_ID = su4.SCHD_ID and su4.COL_NUM = 99

 ) q1
```

Which is the best way to do it?

The dbms IS birt
I temp table on a query will work?

Thanks

Comment: Show your effort to use `case`.  Describe what you wanted and what you got instead.  Be specific.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I added the code, might be helpfull

Comment: Did you try adding new column in case.. end block? just before 
' ...ELSE 'NULL' END as TITOLO_MODULO_SO..'